# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me mande a la dirección de correo electrónico que deseo en función de una lista?

Tags: excel, vba

Soy nuevo utilizando VBA y necesito mandar un correo electrónico automáticamente, adjuntando un archivo excel que previamente he guardado. El problema está en que no sé cómo establecer una orden para que me inserte la dirección de correo electrónico automáticamente en función de dos variables que están en otro excel. Cuando coincida la columna de la tabla de la (Hoja3) tanto en destinatario como en Seccion, con las columnas, Destinatario y Seccion de la tabla (Hoja1), entonces que me utilice ese correo para enviar el archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Sub correo()
    
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
  
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

    'MODIFICAR EL NOMBRE EN FILENAME
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Ficha de Horas " & Range("C6").Value
    FileExtStr = ".xlsx"
    
    wb1.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "AQUÍ DEBERÍA PONERME EL CORREO QUE DESEO"
        '.CC = ""
        '.BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Ficha de Horas " & Range("C6").Value & " " & Range(" C7").Value
        '.Body = ""
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
        '.Send
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hola! Dónde estaría el email que deseas? Trata de que tu ejemplo esté completo, somos buenos imaginando pero no tanto! :) Por favor ve a [edit] y amplía los detalles de tu pregunta, usa datos de prueba, explica qué archivos son (ponles nombres falsos, etc) y explícanos qué va en archivoFalso.xlsx y qué va en otroArchivoFalso.xlsx

Comment: Tienes razón, la he  modificado a ver si así lo entiende mejor. Disculpe